# update an object that contains a list in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, servlets

In my web application, i try to update the object [Chefprojet] that contains a list of entities [Projet]; there is one to many relation between [Chefprojet] and [Projet]. I tried the code bellow, but i'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at dao.Chefprojet2.reaffecterchef(Chefprojet2.java:27)
    at controller.Chefprojet2ControllerServlet.doPost(Chefprojet2ControllerServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.ja
```

Chefprojet2.java

```
public void reaffecterchef(String matricule, String getHiddenValue ){

        try {


            Session session4=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session4.beginTransaction();

                Query query= session4.createQuery("select p.id from Projet p where p.libelle='"+getHiddenValue+"'");
                List list1 = query.list();
                int idp= (int) list1.get(0);

                Projet projet=(Projet) session4.load(Projet.class,idp);             


            Query qry =  session4.createQuery("select chef.id_chef from Chefprojet chef WHERE chef.matricule='" +matricule+ "'");

                List list = qry.list();
                int idm= (int) list.get(0);
                Chefprojet chp=(Chefprojet) session4.load(Chefprojet.class,idm);

                chp.getProjets().add(projet);
                projet.setChefprojet(chp);
                session4.persist(projet);

            session4.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("\n\n Details Added \n");

} catch (HibernateException e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
System.out.println("error");
}
    }
```

Chefprojet2ControllerServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String matricule=request.getParameter("matricule");
        String getHiddenValue=request.getParameter("hidden");
        System.out.println(matricule+" Hidden field Value is :"+getHiddenValue);



        try {


            Chefprojet2 cprojet2 = new Chefprojet2();
            cprojet2.reaffecterchef(matricule, getHiddenValue);



        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Help me pleaase!

Answer (score 0):

Your query (just before line 27) returns empty result set, so your

```
List list = query.list();
```

is emtpy.

Next you are accessing first element of this empty list:

```
int id = (int) list.get(0);
```

and getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`
from `ArrayList` implementation.

Check list if it is empty first: `list.isEmpty()` or something like that...